# MVC -Model with ICollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Here are my 2 models:

VendorMapMessage:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int VendorMapID { get; set; }
    public VendorMap VendorMap { get; set; }
    public int DocumentTypeID { get; set; }
    public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }
    public int IncidentTypeID { get; set; }
    public IncidentType IncidentType { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VendorMapMessagePropertyService> VendorMapMessagePropertyServices { get; set; }
    public string MessageContent { get; set; }'
```

VendorMapMessagePropertyService:

```
    public int ID { get; set; }        
    public int VendorMapMessageID { get; set; }
    public VendorMapMessage VendorMapMessage { get; set; }
    public int PropertyTypeID { get; set; }
    public PropertyType PropertyType { get; set; }
    public int ServiceTypeID { get; set; }
    public ServiceType ServiceType { get; set; }
```

Here is my business logic:

```
 public VendorMapMessage SaveConfirmationMessage(VendorMapMessage source)
    {
        VendorMapMessage result = null;
        try
        {
            using (var db = new ClientAdminContext())
            {
                VendorMapMessage temp = null;
                if (source.ID == default(int))
                {
                    temp = new VendorMapMessage();
                    db.VendorMapMessages.Add(temp);
                    //techdebt remove
                    temp.ID = 84;
                    temp.IncidentTypeID = source.IncidentTypeID;
                    temp.DocumentTypeID = source.DocumentTypeID;
                    temp.MessageContent = source.MessageContent;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp = db.VendorMapMessages.Single(o => o.ID == source.ID);
                }
                temp.IncidentTypeID = source.IncidentTypeID;
                temp.DocumentTypeID = source.DocumentTypeID;
                temp.MessageContent = source.MessageContent;                    
                db.SaveChanges();
                result = temp;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log

            throw;
        }
        return result;
```

Here is my view:

```
<label for="description" class="col-sm-4">Property Type</label>
   <div class="col-md-7">
      <select class="form-control" name="PropertyTypeID" multiple id="prop_type">
       @foreach (PropertyType item in propertyTypes)
          {
          if (@Model.VendorMapMessagePropertyServices.Any(o => o.PropertyTypeID == item.ID))
          {
            <option selected="selected" value=@item.ID>@item.Name</option>
           }
          else
          {
         <option value=@item.ID>@item.Name</option>
           }
         }
       </select>
    </div>
```

The ICollection VendorMapMessagePropertyService displays all the available property types. But I am not able to save the property types that are listed. I am missing a line in business logic where it has to use vendormapmessageID as primary key and link to vendormapmessagepropertyservices 's propertytypeID.

Confused to connect PropertytypeID in vendormapmessagepropertyservice.
(I know model names are crap. I did not think this would become complicated )

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not too clear, but it sounds like you want to save the collection of `VendorMapMessagePropertyService`s tied to the `VendorMapMessage`? If so, you can do this:

```
temp.VendorMapMessagePropertyServices = source.VendorMapMessagePropertyServices;
```

Upon saving changes on the context, this will save the new `VendorMapMessagePropertyService`s and associate them with your `VendorMapMessage`.

**Edit based on comment:** So you want to update `PropertyTypeID` on `VendorMapMessagePropertyService`s that already exist? If so, you need to get them from the context, and then update them, like this:

```
// Get existing property services in the database
IEnumerable<VendorMapMessagePropertyService> allExistingPropertyServices = db.VendorMapMessagePropertyServices;
// Loop through property services from the source...
foreach (VendorMapMessagePropertyService propertyService in source.VendorMapMessagePropertyServices) {
    // Find existing property service
    VendorMapMessagePropertyService existingPropertyService = allExistingPropertyServices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == propertyService.ID);

    // If found, update it
    if (existingPropertyService != null) {
        existingPropertyService.PropertyTypeID = propertyService.PropertyTypeID;
    }
}
```

This would need to be modified if you also want to add property services that are in the source but do not exist in the database.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear; You understood it correct! i already that. I am more specific to save propertytypeID from VendorMapMessagePropertyServices. Do you think i should be more with mentioning propertytypeID @mayabelle

Comment: I tried doing this           'temp.VendorMapMessagePropertyServices.Select(x => x.PropertyTypeID) = source.VendorMapMessagePropertyServices.Select(x => x.PropertyTypeID);'                                                     Still not working

Comment: That won't work - you have to get each object and update each object. Moreover the left side of an assignment cannot be a linq statement like you have. See my update above.

Comment: I am trying this, I am not going to add new propertytype. It will be displaying only the available propertytype and user has to pick from these. I was wondering how does this get matched in temp table.

Comment: In that case you need a `SelectedPropertyTypeID` property on your model, and use a Razor `DropdownListFor` (Google it for an example) to create the dropdown, using your overall list as the possible options and the `SelectedPropertyTypeID` property as the property that the selected one gets set to.

Comment: Sure! I will try with this meanwhile, when I have other things going on in my brain.